# Use Nested interval property to prove that there is c such that f(c)=0?

Tags: real-analysis, numerical-methods

Given that $f(a)<0<f(b)$

Bisect $[a,b]$ with midpoint $c=(a+b)/2$

if $f(c)=0$, we are done.

if $f(c)>0$, we have new interval $[a,c]$

and keep repeating this process then we have nested interval property.

How can I show that there must exist $c$ such that $f(c)=0$?

Comment: You don't have any criterion for preferring the left half-interval to the right.  And yes, you have to assume that $f$ is continuous, otherwise there may not be such a $c$.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is to *prove* the intermediate value theorem, not to *assume* it.  This places the problem at
the level of an elementary real analysis course (where such things are proved) rather than a calculus course
(where such things are assumed).

> What one wishes to prove is that for a *continuous* function $f:[a,b]\to
>   R$ with the property that $f(a)<0<f(b)$ there must be some point
>   $a<c<b$ for which $f(c)=0$.

The requirement is to prove this using the nested interval property.  The method
is standard and it is worth thinking about.  You construct  a shrinking nested sequence of intervals $\{[a_n,b_n]\}$ so that
you can make some claim on each member  $[a_n,b_n]$ of the sequence.  The sequence
shrinks (as it must) to a single point $c$ that belongs to each interval $[a_n,b_n]$ of the sequence.
Then you conclude what you want about this point $c$.

Here are the details. Suppose that there is no point $c$ with $f(c)=0$.
 Use $[a_1,b_1]=[a,b]$.  Split that interval into two equal pieces and
choose the piece $[a_2,b_2]$ so that $f(a_2) < 0 < f(b_2)$. 
(One of the two halves must have this property.)  Do the same to 
$[a_2,b_2]$ and produce an interval  $[a_3,b_3]$ so that $f(a_3) < 0 < f(b_3)$. 
Continuing in this way [or by induction if you are a bit anal] you get a
  a shrinking nested sequence of intervals $\{[a_n,b_n]\}$ with
$f(a_n) < 0 < f(b_n)$.  This shrinks to a point $c$.

Now just use $c$ to get what you want.  You can see that $a_n\to c$ and $b_n\to c$ so,
by continuity $$f(c)=\lim_{n\to\infty} f(a_n) = \lim_{n\to\infty} f(b_n).$$  But
$\lim_{n\to\infty} f(a_n) \leq 0$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty} f(b_n) \geq 0$.  Finally
$f(c)=0$  which contradicts our assumption that we didn't have such a point.

Don't stop here though.  There are other methods for proving the intermediate value theorem and
methods are far more important than results.  In Section 5.8 of our textbook [Elementary Real Analysis](http://classicalrealanalysis.info/Free-Downloads.php)
we ask for several more proofs of the intermediate value property, using other techniques than
the nested interval property.  I would consider those essential to a course in elementary analysis.